# Does Ubuntu have support for the Apt-X codec for bluetooth audio?

Tags: sound, bluetooth, headphones

I cant find any confirmation anywhere. Does anyone know?

If it is not supported, is support planned?

Answer (score 3):

As you can find on wikipedia Apt-X is a "family of proprietary audio codecs". That's another way of saying they want money for it. While open source is good in many things, it's a legal problem to circumvent Apt-X patents and implement it without paying.

Hence, at present Apt-X support on Linux is *very* unlikely, at least as long it is not as widely spread as say mp3...

Answer (score 1):

Sennheiser BTD 500 USB, Bluetooth 3.0 provides APT-X on Linux including Ubuntu.  It does it by posing as a audio device, not a bluetooth radio.  So it handles the APT-X in hardware rather than software on the OS side.